# Number of divisors with the function getopt

Tags: c, string, command-line-arguments, getopt

I'm doing a program which receives a number and gives you the number of divisors.
e.g. 
in the cmd :

```
practica -n 30
```

Expected output:

> 1,2,3,5,6,10,15,30

I have this code:

```
void divisor(char *temp1);
int main(int argc,char **argv){
int option;
char *n;
 while((option =getopt(argc,argv,"n")) !=-1){
  switch(option){
  case 'n':
  n=optarg;
  break;
 }
}

divisor(n);
}

void divisor(char *temp1){
char f=*temp1;
int n=f-'0';
int a;
a=1;
while (a<n)
{
 if(n%a==0)
 printf("%d,",a);
 a++;
}
a=n;
if(n%a==0)
printf("%d",a);
printf("\b ");
}
```

I'm using the command line and the program closes.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Did you try debugging your application to see where it actually goes wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think, your `getopt()` call should look like

```
while((option =getopt(argc,argv,"n:")) !=-1){  //notice the :
```

as you'll be supplying an argument (value) for that option.

That said, in your code, inside `divisor()` function,

```
char f=*temp1;
int n=f-'0';
```

looks wrong. `temp` is a `char` pointer an dereferencing the pointer only gives you the value of the first `char` stored, and the expected value , `30` is not stored as a single `char`, rather it's stored as lexicographical format.

I think, you can use [`strtol()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strtol) to convert the lexicographical representation to `int` value, like

```
int x = strtol(temp, NULL, 0);
```